# Changing NA Values based on cell values in same column in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, missing-symbols

```
V1 <- c("Name", "Paul", "Name", "Sarah", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Name", "Carl", NA, NA, "Name", "Alice", "Name", "Rita")
V2 <- c("Name", "Paul", "Name", "Sarah", "Name", "Sarah", "Name", "Sarah", "Name", "Carl", "Name", "Carl", "Name", "Alice", "Name", "Rita")
df <- data.frame(V1, V2)
df
```

I would like V1 to look like V2. EDIT: In the original dataset, V2 doesnt exist, I created it here to give some example data.

```
      V1    V2
1   Name  Name
2   Paul  Paul
3   Name  Name
4  Sarah Sarah
5   <NA>  Name
6   <NA> Sarah
7   <NA>  Name
8   <NA> Sarah
9   Name  Name
10  Carl  Carl
11  <NA>  Name
12  <NA>  Carl
13  Name  Name
14 Alice Alice
15  Name  Name
16  Rita  Rita
```

I tried the following:

```
#find the positions of missings in V1 
m <- which(is.na(df$V1) == TRUE)
m
[1]  5  6  7  8 11 12

#go to every position and change the value depending on the field that is 2 field above the missing
for (i in m) {
  df$V1[m[i]] <- df$V1[m[i]-2]
}
```

The output is working, but its faulty:

```
      V1    V2
1   Name  Name
2   Paul  Paul
3   Name  Name
4  Sarah Sarah
5   <NA>  Name
6   <NA> Sarah
7   <NA>  Name
8   <NA> Sarah
9   Name  Name
10  Carl  Carl
11  Name  Name
12  Carl  Carl
13  Name  Name
14 Alice Alice
15  Name  Name
16  Rita  Rita
```

Why is it working for the other cells but not the first incident?
Also, I'm trying to avoid for loops, so if there is a more elegant way to do it, I would love to see one!

Comment: Not sure what you are after. the good and faulty data frames appear to be the same?

Comment: Its about V1, not the dataframe. I added V2 to directly see what I want V1 to look like. The original dataframe doesnt have V2 sorted like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `for` loop is looping over `m`, you could directly do

```
m <- which(is.na(df$V1))
for (i in m) df$V1[i] <- df$V1[i-2]
df

#      V1    V2
#1   Name  Name
#2   Paul  Paul
#3   Name  Name
#4  Sarah Sarah
#5   Name  Name
#6  Sarah Sarah
#7   Name  Name
#8  Sarah Sarah
#9   Name  Name
#10  Carl  Carl
#11  Name  Name
#12  Carl  Carl
#13  Name  Name
#14 Alice Alice
#15  Name  Name
#16  Rita  Rita
```

Answer (score 0):

One option involving `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 fill(V1) %>%
 group_by(rleid = with(rle(V1), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 mutate(V1 = ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 0 , "Name", V1)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)

   V1    V2   
   <chr> <chr>
 1 Name  Name 
 2 Paul  Paul 
 3 Name  Name 
 4 Sarah Sarah
 5 Name  Name 
 6 Sarah Sarah
 7 Name  Name 
 8 Sarah Sarah
 9 Name  Name 
10 Carl  Carl 
11 Name  Name 
12 Carl  Carl 
13 Name  Name 
14 Alice Alice
15 Name  Name 
16 Rita  Rita
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, where you use `matrix` to reformulate the problem:

```
df$V2 <- as.vector(t(apply(matrix(df$V1,nrow = 2), 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][cumsum(!is.na(x))])))
```

such that

```
> df
      V1    V2
1   Name  Name
2   Paul  Paul
3   Name  Name
4  Sarah Sarah
5   <NA>  Name
6   <NA> Sarah
7   <NA>  Name
8   <NA> Sarah
9   Name  Name
10  Carl  Carl
11  <NA>  Name
12  <NA>  Carl
13  Name  Name
14 Alice Alice
15  Name  Name
16  Rita  Rita
```